# remove redundant css rules from dynamic website

Tags: optimization, css, css-selectors, minify

I'm trying to reduce the size of my CSS file. It is from a template which is very CSS & JS heavy. Even with CSSMin the CSS file size is 250kb.

Whilst I use alot of the CSS - I know I dont use it all. So I'm trying to work out which styles can be removed. I'm aware of Dust-Me selector - but that only takes a static look at the website. With HTML5 and CSS3 - websites are now very dynamic, and most of my CSS occurs from dynamic events, or 'responsive' events i.e. Bootstrap.

**Question:** Is there a tool which 'records' all my CSS use on a website for a perioid of time, so I can go and click/hover/move over each element and interact with my site. Then at the end let me know which styles were & were not used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**250kb** is really such a big figure for just CSS files.
The templates generally have all the CSS required for all the pages in a single file.
I would suggest:

> Do not *cut* your CSS code, they might be needed some point of time.

Instead i would suggest, break your CSS file into number of small files for different page stylings,
such as a different CSS for *login* page, different CSS file for *home* page, etc.
Read your own `CSS` and `HTML` code vigorously to find out *which significant part of CSS code is used in which HTML section*.

**Update:**
You may try [Removed Unused CSS - CSS optimizer](http://unused-css.com/).
I personally did not use it just hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Asif - but that wont work - the site is basically as "SaaS" application - and the majority of CSS is reused dynamically on many pages - so it makes more sense for me to make one minfied CSS file that is sent to the browser once and cached for a long time

Comment: you said that _Then at the end let me know which styles were & were not used?_, If I would be the template designer than I would never put my efforts in providing codes that _were not going to be used_

Comment: The template is a generic bought template that has ALOT of functionality and flexibility. I just dont use it all in my website. So the styles + codes could have been used... but they werent in my case

Answer (score 1):

CSS Usage is a great extension for firefox. It tells which css are currently used in a page.

Link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage/

Comment: hmmm.. thats 'close' - the only problem is it requires me to press 'scan' each and every time I do a single thing on the website - and that will be ALOT for my site. Do you know if there is something like this, but automatic?

Answer (score 1):

There are two tools that I think might help you out.

[helium](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) is a javascript tool that will discover any unused css rules.

[csscss](http://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss/) is a source code analyzer that will report any duplication. I'm biased because I wrote csscss precisely because I couldn't find anything that did this. But many people seem to find it useful.